# Selecting elements of individual pages of an app

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove two elements from the page of my web app (or the one I'm developing anyone). This is for responsiveness reasons, the elements look great on mobile devices but not very good on desktops. So, I'd like to target the pages by url, then get the elements and hide them.

I'm using node.js but I'm a bit of a noob. Is this something I could achieve with React or Vue or something like that. I tried with jQuery but with no success.

This is the html:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <section id="dot1">
      <h6>Text Here</h6>
    </section>
      <section id="dot2">
    <h6>Text Here</h6>
    </section>
    <section id="studiesWp"><img src="/images/ms.png">
      <h1>Text Here</h1>
      <p>Text Here</p><a href="url/">Text Here</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

So, I want to hide the two elements: #dot1 & #dot2. The rest of it can stay.

Here's a little jQuery function I tried:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // Check media queries
  if($(window).width() >= 769) {
    // Get pathname of page
    var page = window.location.pathname;
    // If pathname matches any of these
    if(page = 'profilePage','projectsPage','contact'){

      // Remove two elements
      $('#dot1').css('display','none');
      $('#dot2').css('display','none');
    }
    else{
      $('#dot1').css('display','block');
      $('#dot2').css('display','block');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: its probably better to do this with css but if you want to do it with js then you should call your method on `$(window).resize` instead of `$(window).load`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best to do with CSS3, which has media queries to apply styling only if the viewport it's being seen has certain properties.

### Desktop-only css

So, if we want to create an element that's only visible on phones, and our css was desktop only, we'd probably create something like this:

```
/* This example will not work correctly, look below for the full code! */
.phone-only {
    display: none;
}
```

### Media Query

To make that style only apply to larger screens, we'll use a `@media` query. We need to apply styles to only smartphones, or devices with a screen width of less then `769px`. In CSS, we write that as `min-width: 769px`, and then wrap it with a media query like this: `@media (min-width: 769px)`.

When we wrap the style we made earlier inside of our `@media` query, we get a css rule that hides an element on phones.

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
   .phone-only {
       display: none;
   }
}
```

and use `class="phone-only"`.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks.